# How to tell if a python package installation includes precompiled binaries?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Is there a reliable way to determine if when installing a Python package with pip/conda if the installer includes precompiled binaries? I would like to exclude or at least know when this happens. Sometimes this can be determined from looking at the setup/project in the source distribution or by the name of the whl file, but not always. Mostly it's important to have a reliable Yes/No/Unsure signal to help prioritize further investigation.

Comment: Are you looking for the `--no-binary` option in pip?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to figure out from pip's metadata whether a package was built from source or downloaded as a wheel, but I did find a way to scan a directory of packages for binaries.

First, run `python -m site`. This shows you a list of directories where Python can load packages from.

Pick one of those to scan.

Run one of these commands:

Linux:

```
(cd $PACKAGE_DIR && find . -type f -exec file {} \; | awk -F'[/:]' '/ELF/ && !a[$2]++ {print $2}' )
```

Replace $PACKAGE_DIR with one of the directories from before.

OSX:

```
(cd $PACKAGE_DIR && find . -type f -exec file {} \; | awk -F'[/:]' '/Mach-O/ && !a[$2]++ {print $2}' )
```

Replace $PACKAGE_DIR with one of the directories from before.

This gives you a list of packages that contain shared objects. These might have been built from source - pip will do that if no wheel is available. But pip will preferentially use wheels unless `--no-binary` is used.

It is also worth noting that pip can install binaries into `~/.local/bin`. Those can get run if that's on your $PATH.